# Dynamic dropdown selection for dynamic rows not just first row

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I have created a form for entering product data which sends the results back to the mysql database. I have a dropdown/select id named 'attribute_name' and the other 'attribute_value' I have managed to send the results back to the database and that is working great. I would however like to restrict the user to only choosing values based on the name so if they selected **size** they would only have the values of small, medium, large and not black, camo, purple from **colour** and vice versa.

The script at the bottom works on the first row but not on any other rows as shown in the screenshots.

Working

[image]

Not working

[image]

Code

```
    <?php
    include 'assets/processes/db-connection.php';
    $query = "SELECT * 
                FROM attribute_name;";
    $query_run = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    $att_name = "<select name='attribute_name' id='attribute_name' class='form-control country'>";
    $att_name .= "<option value='0'></option>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run)) {
    $att_name .= "<option value='{$row['attribute_name']}'>{$row['attribute_name']}</option>";
    }
    $att_name .= "</select>"
    ?>
      <?php
    include 'assets/processes/db-connection.php';
    $query = "SELECT `attribute`.*, `attribute_name`.*
                FROM `attribute` 
                    LEFT JOIN `attribute_name` ON `attribute`.`attribute_name_id` = `attribute_name`.`attribute_name_id`;";
    $query_run = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    $att_value = "<select name='attribute_id' id='attribute_value' class='form-control'>";
    $att_value .= "<option value='0'></option>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run)) {
    $att_value .= "<option data-parent='{$row['attribute_name']}' value='{$row['attribute_id']}'>{$row['attribute_value']}</option>";
    }
    $att_value .= "</select>"
    ?>

        <div id="wrapper">
          <div id="form_div">
            <table class="table table-hover text-nowrap" id="attribute_table">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Value</th>
                  <th colspan="1">Action</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tr id="row1">
                <td>
                  <?php echo $att_name; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <?php echo $att_value; ?>
                </td>
                <td><input class="btn btn-block btn-primary" type="button" onclick="add_attribute_row();" value="+"></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
        <script>
          $('#attribute_name').change(function() { var parent = $(this).val(); $('#attribute_value').children().each(function() { if ($(this).data('parent') != parent) { $(this).hide(); } else $(this).show(); }); });
          </script>
```

This code is edited for use on stackoverflow

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="form_div">
        <table class="table table-hover text-nowrap" id="attribute_table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Value</th>
                    <th colspan="1">Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tr id="row1">
                <td>
                    <select name='attribute_name' id='attribute_name' class='form-control'>
                    <option value='0'></option>
                    <option value='Colour'>Colour</option>
                    <option value='Size'>Size</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select name='attribute_id' id='attribute_value' class='form-control'>
                    <option value='0'></option>
                    <option data-parent='Colour' value='1'>Black</option>
                    <option data-parent='Colour' value='2'>Camo</option>
                    <option data-parent='Colour' value='3'>Purple</option>
                    <option data-parent='Size' value='4'>Small</option>
                    <option data-parent='Size' value='5'>Medium</option>
                    <option data-parent='Size' value='6'>Large</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td><input class="btn btn-block btn-primary" type="button" onclick="add_attribute_row();" value="+"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
function add_attribute_row() {
    $rowno = $("#attribute_table tr").length;
    $rowno = $rowno + 1;
    $("#attribute_table tr:last").after("<tr id='row" + $rowno + "'><td><select name='attribute_name' id='attribute_name' class='form-control'><option value='0'></option><option value='Colour'>Colour</option><option value='Size'>Size</option></select></td><td><select name='attribute_id' id='attribute_value' class='form-control'><option value='0'></option><option data-parent='Colour' value='1'>Black</option><option data-parent='Colour' value='2'>Camo</option><option data-parent='Colour' value='3'>Purple</option><option data-parent='Size' value='4'>Small</option><option data-parent='Size' value='5'>Medium</option><option data-parent='Size' value='6'>Large</option></select></td><td><input class='btn btn-block btn-primary' type='button' value='-' onclick=del_att_row('row" + $rowno + "')></td></tr>");
}
function del_att_row(rowno) {
    $('#' + rowno).remove();
};
</script>
<script>
    $('#attribute_name').bind('change', function () {
        var parent = $(this).val();
        $('#attribute_value').children().each(function () {
            if ($(this).data('parent') != parent) {
                $(this).hide();
            } else
                $(this).show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You are essentially creating only on line yourself...  $att_name should become : $att_name[0] for example so: $att_name[0] = "<select name='attribute_name' id='attribute_name' class='form-control country'>";
$att_name[0] .= "<option value='0'></option>"; etc...  later you loop through the result starting the loop after thead... this applies also to $att_value which should be $att_value[0] , $att_value[1] etc ... add a $i = 0; and ++$i in the end of each while loop.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Your current example cannot be replicated and does not even offer Example data.

Comment: @Shlomtzion I added $i=0; and ++$i at the end of each while loop but it had no affect on the dropdown selections when I added a new row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First of all, you are not allowed to use **duplicate ID**. You should use **class** instead. Check this answer [Class vs ID](https://stackoverflow.com/a/719612/9387984).
2. Secondly, I've changed your `change` event with `.on('change')` which will work for dynamically added select. Check this sample [JQuery .on('change')](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14942187/9387984).
3. Lastly, you don't want to select **all** select with class `attribute-name`, you need to find the select on that particular row. You can do this by using **.closest('tr')** selector to select the current row `<tr>` where the event happened,  and then use **`.find('.attribute-value')** which will traverse and find element with the class` attribute-value`.

From the documentation:

- The [`.closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) selector traverses up the DOM to find the parent that matches the conditions.
- The [`.find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) selector traverses down the DOM where the event occurred, that matches the conditions.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="form_div">
        <table class="table table-hover text-nowrap" id="attribute_table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Value</th>
                    <th colspan="1">Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tr id="row1">
                <td>
                    <select name='attribute_name' id='attribute_name' class='form-control attribute_name'>
                    <option value='0'></option>
                    <option value='Colour'>Colour</option>
                    <option value='Size'>Size</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select name='attribute_id' id='attribute_value' class='form-control attribute_value'>
                    <option data-parent='0' value='0'></option>
                    <option data-parent='Colour' value='1'>Black</option>
                    <option data-parent='Colour' value='2'>Camo</option>
                    <option data-parent='Colour' value='3'>Purple</option>
                    <option data-parent='Size' value='4'>Small</option>
                    <option data-parent='Size' value='5'>Medium</option>
                    <option data-parent='Size' value='6'>Large</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td><input class="btn btn-block btn-primary" type="button" onclick="add_attribute_row();" value="+"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
function add_attribute_row() {
    $rowno = $("#attribute_table tr").length;
    $("#attribute_table tr:last").after("<tr id='row" + $rowno + "'><td><select name='attribute_name' id='attribute_name' class='form-control attribute_name'><option value='0'></option><option value='Colour'>Colour</option><option value='Size'>Size</option></select></td><td><select name='attribute_id' id='attribute_value' class='form-control attribute_value'><option data-parent='0' value='0'></option><option data-parent='Colour' value='1'>Black</option><option data-parent='Colour' value='2'>Camo</option><option data-parent='Colour' value='3'>Purple</option><option data-parent='Size' value='4'>Small</option><option data-parent='Size' value='5'>Medium</option><option data-parent='Size' value='6'>Large</option></select></td><td><input class='btn btn-block btn-primary' type='button' value='-' onclick=del_att_row('row" + $rowno + "')></td></tr>");
}
function del_att_row(rowno) {
    $('#' + rowno).remove();
};
</script>
<script>
$(document).on('change', '.attribute_name', function () {
        var parent = $(this).val();  $(this).closest('tr').find('.attribute_value').children().each(function () {
            if ($(this).data('parent') != parent) {
                $(this).hide();
            } else
                $(this).show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will illustrate the need and the way! - Took your code and changed it a bit - for the example I created two arrays in one divided by the name of the var and counted by the amount it contains... I also placed two loops in and around the html in order to achieve the names - main loop that in our case only runs twice (this code example) and inner loop for the values of each name... :

```
<?php

$att_data["Colour"][] = "Black";
$att_data["Colour"][] = "Blue";
$att_data["Colour"][] = "Red";
$att_data["Colour"][] = "Green";

$att_data["Size"][] = "Large";
$att_data["Size"][] = "Small";
$att_data["Size"][] = "Medium";
$att_data["Size"][] = "XL";
echo '<pre>';
print_r($att_data);

$i = 0;
$s = 0;
?>


    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="form_div">
            <table class="table table-hover text-nowrap" id="attribute_table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Value</th>
                        <th colspan="1">Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <?php
                foreach($att_data as $key => $d){ ?>
                    <tr id="row1">
                        <td>
                            <select name='attribute_name' id='attribute_name' class='form-control'>
                                <option value='<?php echo $key; ?>'><?php echo $key; ?></option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select name='attribute_id' id='attribute_value' class='form-control'>
                                <?php
                                foreach ($att_data[$key] as $val){
                                    ?><option value='<?php echo $val; ?>'><?php echo $val; ?></option><?php
                                } ?>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td><input class="btn btn-block btn-primary" type="button" onclick="add_attribute_row();" value="+"></td>
                    </tr> <?php
                }
                ?>

            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This will output this:
[image]

This should explain how to collect and distribute data! :) - the keys in my case Colour etc are the names... and the values are the values!
no need for too many variables, a nice array with correct keys does the data collecting better!

Comment: Your answer does not solve the problem. It works for a fixed select option, but what the OP requires is a dynamic set select-option. And the problem the OP face, JQuery change event only works for the first row.