# How to use Bootstrap Tables to select several different tags to filter a table to show all records that contain at least one of the selected tags?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-table

I have built a table using Bootstrap Table version 1.21.2, which reads and parses data from a JSON file. Some entries in this table contain multiple tags.

I want to add a filter above the table, which allows to select multiple tags, so that only all records are displayed, which contain at least one of these selected tags. How can I create such a filter? I would be grateful for any advice on this.

@Sajjad Ali
Below you can see an example table to get an idea about the setup.
My goal is to create a kind of drop-down menu to the left of the search box, where checkmarks can be placed next to tags.
However, the last column with the tags should be hidden.

The comment of @Yogi (which has been deleted in the meantime) gave me an additional idea. Above the selectable tags, there should be an additional button in the drop-down menu, which can be used to switch between AND/OR.

I already considered the suggestion of @Yogi with "data-filter-control-multiple-search" and tried to set the following attributes.

```
data-filter-control-multiple-search="true"
data-filter-control-multiple-search-delimiter=","
data-filter-options="{ filterAlgorithm: 'or' }"
```

I don't know how to achieve the described goal and would appreciate any further hints, tips or even code.

```js
// Contents for test.js
// Represents JSON of the data

var data = `[{"decisionID":"1",
"decisionDate":"2021-03-11",
"caseIdentifier":"Sample case identifier",
"decisionText":"Sample Text",
"tags":"Warning",
"courtCode":"RBAMS",
"jurisdiction":"NL"},
{"decisionID":"2",
"decisionDate":"2023-05-04",
"caseIdentifier":"Sample case identifier",
"decisionText":"Sample Text",
"tags":"Employment,Fine",
"courtCode":"EuGH",
"jurisdiction":"EU"},
{"decisionID":"3",
"decisionDate":"2022-11-21",
"caseIdentifier":"Sample case identifier",
"decisionText":"Sample Text",
"tags":"Theft",
"courtCode":"OLGNB",
"jurisdiction":"DE"},
{"decisionID":"4",
"decisionDate":"2022-11-21",
"caseIdentifier":"Sample case identifier",
"decisionText":"Sample Text",
"tags":"Theft",
"courtCode":"OLGNB",
"jurisdiction":"DE"},
{"decisionID":"5",
"decisionDate":"2020-05-12",
"caseIdentifier":"Sample case identifier",
"decisionText":"Sample Text",
"tags":"Urgent proceedings",
"courtCode":"VwGH",
"jurisdiction":"AU"},
{"decisionID":"6",
"decisionDate":"2021-04-15",
"caseIdentifier":"Sample case identifier",
"decisionText":"Sample Text",
"tags":"Commercial law,Theft,Commercial law",
"courtCode":"OGH",
"jurisdiction":"AT"},
{"decisionID":"7",
"decisionDate":"2021-05-31",
"caseIdentifier":"Sample case identifier",
"decisionText":"Sample Text",
"tags":"penalty payment",
"courtCode":"AGWI",
"jurisdiction":"AG"},
{"decisionID":"8",
"decisionDate":"2019-08-19",
"caseIdentifier":"Sample case identifier",
"decisionText":"Sample Text",
"tags":"Fine",
"courtCode":"-",
"jurisdiction":"null"},
{"decisionID":"9",
"decisionDate":"2021-03-11",
"caseIdentifier":"Sample case identifier",
"decisionText":"Sample Text",
"tags":"Injunctive relief",
"courtCode":"RBAMS",
"jurisdiction":"NL"},
{"decisionID":"10",
"decisionDate":"2022-11-22",
"caseIdentifier":"Sample case identifier",
"decisionText":"Sample Text",
"tags":"Insurance",
"courtCode":"EuGH",
"jurisdiction":"EU"}]
`;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width,
                initial-scale=1,
                shrink-to-fit=no">
<title>
    load data from json file
    into a bootstrap table
</title>

<!-- Include Bootstrap for styling -->
<link rel="stylesheet"
        href=
"https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Include the Bootstrap Table
CSS for the table -->
<link rel="stylesheet"
        href=
"https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.16.0/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <!-- <h1 class="text text-success text-center ">
    GeeksforGeeks
    </h1>
    <h6 class="text text-success text-center">
    A computer science portal for geeks
    </h6> -->
    <table class="table-striped border-success"
    data-toolbar="#filterContainer"
    data-sort-order="desc"
    data-toolbar-align="right"
    data-filter-control="false"
    data-filter-control-container="#filterContainer"
    data-filter-control-visible="true"
    data-search="true"
    data-select-item-name="selectItemName"
    data-sort-name="decisionDate"
    data-pagination="true"
    data-side-pagination="client"
    data-show-footer="false"
    data-page-size="10"
    data-page-list="[10, 20, 50, 100, 200]"
    data-cookie="true"
    data-cookie-expire="1y"
    data-cookie-id-table="courtdecisiontable"
    data-cookie-storage="sessionStorage"
    data-cookie-secure="true"
    data-filter-control-multiple-search="true"
    data-filter-control-multiple-search-delimiter=","
    data-filter-options="{ filterAlgorithm: 'and' }"
    >
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="decisionID" data-visible="false">
            <span class="text-success">
                decisionID
            </span>
            </th>
            <th data-field="decisionDate" data-sortable="true">
            <span class="text-success">
                Date
            </span>
            </th>
            <th data-field="caseIdentifier" data-sortable="true">
            <span class="text-success">
                Case Identifier
            </span>
            </th>
            <th data-field="courtCode" data-sortable="true">
            <span class="text-success">
                Court Code
            </span>
            </th>
            <th data-field="jurisdiction" data-sortable="true" style="text-align:center;">
            <span class="text-success">
                Country
            </span>
            </th>
            <th data-field="decisionText">
            <span class="text-success">
                Decision Summary
            </span>
            </th>
            <th data-field="tags">
            <span class="text-success">
                Tags
            </span>
            </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>

<!-- Include jQuery and other required files for Bootstrap -->
<script src=
"https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js">
</script>
<script src=
"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js">
</script>
<script src=
"https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>

<!-- Include the JavaScript file for Bootstrap table -->
<script src=
"https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.16.0/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js">
</script>

<!-- Include the file where the JSON data is stored -->
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="test.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

    // Use the given data to create
    // the table and display it
    $('table').bootstrapTable({
        data: mydata
    });
    });

    // Parse the imported data as JSON
    // and store it
    var mydata = JSON.parse(data)
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please show us your approach what you did, reproducible code. etc.

Comment: @KTretakov line in 4th para confusing me... the confusing part is after "Above the selectable tags". what do you mean by "there should be an additional button in the drop-down menu,". What I understand so far is that you want a single drop down in side it there will be radio buttons to select algorithm. below it the all categories with checkboxes are listed (obviously working of the check boxes too). Am i right?

Comment: @m-naeem66622
Thank you very much for your detailed answer.
I have imagined this similar to a kind of toggle switch.
For example, on the left there should be "AND", in the middle the toggle switch and on the right "OR".
When clicking on the toggle switch, the selection between AND/OR should change accordingly.

Comment: @KTretakov oh i see you can use switch in bootstrap to get the requirement. it is easy to set it up.. then you have to change the coditions of `if` body for the selection between `and` & `or`.

Comment: @m-naeem66622 Thanks for your reply. I tried to insert the following div block, but it stays with "AND" and does not change. <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input algo-option" id="customSwitches" name="filterAlgorithm" id="andAlgorithm" value="and">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitches">And/Or</label>
</div>

Answer (score 1):

## What I Had Changed or Added?

### 1- Change Tags type in JSON Data

I had changed the data type of tags from string to an array that will help us a lot later to deal with filters. I changed the existing code to the following:

```
// Parse the imported data as JSON and store it
var mydata = JSON.parse(data).map((elem) => ({
    ...elem, // copy the whole object
    tags: elem.tags // replace the tags value with our own
        .split(",") // splitting the string by ,
        .map((tag) => tag.trim()) // remove trailing white spaces
        .filter(Boolean), // filter the empty string elements
}));
```

### 2- Lets Add a Dropdown And Update it

Added a dropdown inside `div#filterContainer` with radio buttons but without any tags (we will add it dynamically). You can see the related `html` in the code snippet that is embed.

Then, I added reference and `onchange handle` to the all of the `tags checkboxes` and `algorithms radio buttons`.

```
// Get reference to the tag checkboxes and algorithm radio buttons
var $tagCheckboxes;
var $algoOptions = $(".algo-option");

// Listen for changes in the tag checkboxes and algorithm radio buttons
$(document).on("change", ".tag-checkbox", handleOnChange);
$algoOptions.on("change", handleOnChange);
```

> 1. Keep in mind that `$tagCheckboxes` has only declaration because we will define it after adding the tags dynamically.
> 2. `.tag-checkbox` has different syntax because of the problem with dynamically updating the DOM. For further details read [CodeChimps's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14942048/why-is-my-jquery-onchange-not-working-for-dynamically-added-selects/14942137#14942137). And the solution to it is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14942048/why-is-my-jquery-onchange-not-working-for-dynamically-added-selects/42779401#42779401)

Then, I had wrote `addTags()` function to dynamically update the DOM with tags and invoked the function in `$(document).ready` event. After updating the DOM, assigned the reference of the `tags checkboxes` to the `$tagCheckboxes`.

```
// Invoke the function to add tags
addTags();
// Get reference to the tag checkboxes
$tagCheckboxes = $(".tag-checkbox");
```

### 3- Lets Add Filtering Mechanism

For filtering records according to the selected tags and filter algorithm I added a separate function `handleOnChange()`. It will invoke whenever value of `checkboxes` or `radio-buttons` change.

The desired requiremnt (filter with tags) cannot be fulfill by just setting `filterAlgorithm` to `"and"` & `"or"`. It will work indeed like normally with `id` because it has only one value but we have multples values inside `tags` key. For overcome this issue custom `filterAlgorithm` come into the picture. We can give own funtion to `filterAlgorithm`. See [method](https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/api/methods/#filterby) and [example](https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/#methods/filter-by.html) for more detail.

Here the [gist](https://gist.github.com/m-naeem66622/b53addaed2580d0fec5c7520a6ebaf37) if you want to understand how one line statement work. The answer is already became too long so that's why.

> When no tags are selected with `"or"` filterAlgorith, no records are shown. And when no tags are selected with `"and"` filterAlgorithm, all records are shown. If you already know just chill, otherwise want to know **Why** then have a look upon the [gist](https://gist.github.com/m-naeem66622/b53addaed2580d0fec5c7520a6ebaf37).

### Issue Faced After Converting Tags To Array

After converting string to an array, you will never search for tags within a table using search bar. For this you have to format the column. It is easy to format the column by adding attribute `data-formatter`. Here is an [example](https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/#column-options/formatter.html).

1. Add `data-formatter` attribute to the column header with function.

```
<th data-field="tags" data-formatter="tagsFormatter" data-visible="false">
    <span class="text-success"> Tags </span>
</th>
```

2. Then intialize a function named that you had previously added to the attribute which accepts value as an argument. Below code will join an array with `", "` and return as a string. Then you will able to search with tags too.

```
function tagsFormatter(value) {
    return value.join(", ");
}
```

## Talk Is Cheap Show Me The Code

Here it is working code snippet according to the requirement. Comment below if something you want.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,
                initial-scale=1,
                shrink-to-fit=no" />
  <title>load data from json file into a bootstrap table</title>

  <!-- Include Bootstrap for styling -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

  <!-- Include the Bootstrap Table
CSS for the table -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.16.0/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <!-- <h1 class="text text-success text-center ">
    GeeksforGeeks
    </h1>
    <h6 class="text text-success text-center">
    A computer science portal for geeks
    </h6> -->
    <div id="filterContainer">
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Select Filters
                    </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu text-dark" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
          <span class="dropdown-item">
                            <div class="form-check">
                                <input
                                    class="form-check-input algo-option"
                                    type="radio"
                                    name="filterAlgorithm"
                                    id="andAlgorithm"
                                    value="and"
                                    checked
                                />
                                <label
                                    class="form-check-label"
                                    for="exampleRadios1"
                                    >And</label
                                >
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-check">
                                <input
                                    class="form-check-input algo-option"
                                    type="radio"
                                    name="filterAlgorithm"
                                    id="orAlgorithm"
                                    value="or"
                                />
                                <label
                                    class="form-check-label"
                                    for="exampleRadios2"
                                    >Or</label
                                >
                            </div>
                        </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <table class="table-striped border-success" data-toolbar="#filterContainer" data-sort-order="desc" data-toolbar-align="left" data-filter-control="false" data-filter-control-container="#filterContainer" data-filter-control-visible="true" data-search="true"
      data-select-item-name="selectItemName" data-sort-name="decisionDate" data-pagination="true" data-side-pagination="client" data-show-footer="false" data-page-size="10" data-page-list="[10, 20, 50, 100, 200]" data-cookie="true" data-cookie-expire="1y"
      data-cookie-id-table="courtdecisiontable" data-cookie-storage="sessionStorage" data-cookie-secure="true">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th data-field="decisionID" data-visible="false">
            <span class="text-success"> decisionID </span>
          </th>
          <th data-field="decisionDate" data-sortable="true">
            <span class="text-success"> Date </span>
          </th>
          <th data-field="caseIdentifier" data-sortable="true">
            <span class="text-success"> Case Identifier </span>
          </th>
          <th data-field="courtCode" data-sortable="true">
            <span class="text-success"> Court Code </span>
          </th>
          <th data-field="jurisdiction" data-sortable="true" style="text-align: center">
            <span class="text-success"> Country </span>
          </th>
          <th data-field="decisionText">
            <span class="text-success"> Decision Summary </span>
          </th>
          <th data-field="tags" data-formatter="tagsFormatter" data-visible="false">
            <span class="text-success"> Tags </span>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>

  <!-- Include jQuery and other required files for Bootstrap -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Include the JavaScript file for Bootstrap table -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.16.0/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Include the file where the JSON data is stored -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var data = `[{"decisionID":"1",
"decisionDate":"2021-03-11",
"caseIdentifier":"Sample case identifier",
"decisionText":"Sample Text",
"tags":"Warning",
"courtCode":"RBAMS",
"jurisdiction":"NL"},
{"decisionID":"2",
"decisionDate":"2023-05-04",
"caseIdentifier":"Sample case identifier",
"decisionText":"Sample Text",
"tags":"Employment,Fine, Theft",
"courtCode":"EuGH",
"jurisdiction":"EU"},
{"decisionID":"3",
"decisionDate":"2022-11-21",
"caseIdentifier":"Sample case identifier",
"decisionText":"Sample Text",
"tags":"Theft",
"courtCode":"OLGNB",
"jurisdiction":"DE"},
{"decisionID":"4",
"decisionDate":"2022-11-21",
"caseIdentifier":"Sample case identifier",
"decisionText":"Sample Text",
"tags":"Theft",
"courtCode":"OLGNB",
"jurisdiction":"DE"},
{"decisionID":"5",
"decisionDate":"2020-05-12",
"caseIdentifier":"Sample case identifier",
"decisionText":"Sample Text",
"tags":"Urgent proceedings",
"courtCode":"VwGH",
"jurisdiction":"AU"},
{"decisionID":"6",
"decisionDate":"2021-04-15",
"caseIdentifier":"Sample case identifier",
"decisionText":"Sample Text",
"tags":"Commercial law, Warning , Fine ,Theft,  ,Commercial law",
"courtCode":"OGH",
"jurisdiction":"AT"},
{"decisionID":"7",
"decisionDate":"2021-05-31",
"caseIdentifier":"Sample case identifier",
"decisionText":"Sample Text",
"tags":"penalty payment",
"courtCode":"AGWI",
"jurisdiction":"AG"},
{"decisionID":"8",
"decisionDate":"2019-08-19",
"caseIdentifier":"Sample case identifier",
"decisionText":"Sample Text",
"tags":"Fine",
"courtCode":"-",
"jurisdiction":"null"},
{"decisionID":"9",
"decisionDate":"2021-03-11",
"caseIdentifier":"Sample case identifier",
"decisionText":"Sample Text",
"tags":"Injunctive relief, Warning",
"courtCode":"RBAMS",
"jurisdiction":"NL"},
{"decisionID":"10",
"decisionDate":"2022-11-22",
"caseIdentifier":"Sample case identifier",
"decisionText":"Sample Text",
"tags":"Insurance",
"courtCode":"EuGH",
"jurisdiction":"EU"}]
`;


    // Get reference to the algorithm radio buttons
    var $tagCheckboxes;
    var $algoOptions = $(".algo-option");

    // Listen for changes in the tag checkboxes and algorithm radio buttons
    // $tagCheckboxes.on("change", "span", handleOnChange);
    $(document).on("change", ".tag-checkbox", handleOnChange);
    $algoOptions.on("change", handleOnChange);

    $(document).ready(function() {
      // Use the given data to create table and display it
      $("table").bootstrapTable({
        data: mydata,
      });

      // Invoke the function to add tags
      addTags();

      // Get reference to the tag checkboxes
      $tagCheckboxes = $(".tag-checkbox");
    });

    function tagsFormatter(value) {
      return value.join(", ");
    }

    // Parse the imported data as JSON and store it
    var mydata = JSON.parse(data).map((elem) => ({
      ...elem, // copy the whole object
      tags: elem.tags // replace the tags value with our own
        .split(",") // splitting the string by ,
        .map((tag) => tag.trim()) // remove trailing white spaces
        .filter(Boolean), // filter the empty string elements
    }));

    function handleOnChange() {
      var selectedTags = [];
      // Get the selected tags
      $tagCheckboxes.each(function() {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
          selectedTags.push($(this).val());
        }
      });

      // Get the checked algo-option
      var $checkedAlgoOption = $algoOptions.filter(":checked");

      // Filter the table data
      $("table").bootstrapTable(
        "filterBy", {
          tags: selectedTags
        }, {
          filterAlgorithm: (row, filters) => {
            // Check if all of the selected tags are present in the row tags
            if ($checkedAlgoOption.val() === "and") {
              return filters.tags.every((tag) =>
                row.tags.includes(tag)
              );
            }

            // Check if any of the selected tags are present in the row tags
            if ($checkedAlgoOption.val() === "or") {
              return filters.tags.some((tag) =>
                row.tags.includes(tag)
              );
            }
          },
        }
      );
    }

    function addTags() {
      var allTags = [];
      // Loop through the JSON data and extract all the tags
      mydata.forEach((obj) => {
        allTags = allTags.concat(obj.tags);
      });

      // Remove duplicates from the tag array
      var uniqueTags = [...new Set(allTags)];

      // Add the unique tags to the dropdown
      uniqueTags.forEach((tag) => {
        $(".dropdown-menu").append(
          `<span class="dropdown-item">
                            <input class="tag-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="${tag}"" id="tag-${tag}"/>
                            <label for="tag-${tag}">${tag}</label>
                        </span>`
        );
      });
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer as well as for the code.

What is still not ideal: The selection of the tags sometimes works and sometimes not, depending on how exactly you hit with the mouse. When you have multiple tags selected, it's not clear how to get out of the dropdown again.

The dropdown menu should also be optimized for mobile view.
If you click on the word next to the selection box, the dropdown menu should not close directly.

Perhaps an additional button to close the dropdown menu at the bottom would be conceivable.

Comment: @KTretakov it is because the issue is we had used a dropdown that close whenever an option is selected. when you click on label (text aside the checkbox) this will check or uncheck the check box depending on previous condition. if you want to overcome this issue you can use collapse instead of dropdown. collapse will be the good option.

Comment: @KTretakov you just have to replace the dropdown with collapse component of bootstrap.. if you found this answer helpful. make upvote and accept the answer by clicking on tick. this will also becomes helpful for other to choose the best answer that really work

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried replacing "dropdown" with "collapse" and after that no selection was displayed above the table. I don't know where exactly to replace it and I don't know what to specify for the attribute "data-target".

Comment: can you just show mw te approach that you did with collapse and what you had changed??? So that i can figure it out..

Comment: @KTretakov upload your code to https://gist.github.com and attch the link in the comment